# sending csv file as an attachment

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

i have tried the following code of sending email with attachment. it does show attachment while trying to send but the problem is it only send email with subject and body but without the attachment. i will appreciate your help

```
 emailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailButton);

 textTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtenterserial);
 textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtenterseri);
 textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtenters);

 emailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         String to = textTo.getText().toString();
         String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
         String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         i.setType("text/plain");
         File data = null;
         try {
             Date dateVal = new Date();
             String filename = dateVal.toString();
             data = File.createTempFile("Report", ".csv");
             Log.d("vvvvvv", data.toString());
              FileWriter out = (FileWriter) GenerateCsv.generateCsvFile(data, "Name,Data1");
             //Log.d("SSSSHOOOOW", out.toString());
             i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(data));
             i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
             i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
             i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "E-mail"));
          } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
 });


 public static  class GenerateCsv {
     public static  FileWriter generateCsvFile(File sFileName,String fileContent) {

         FileWriter writer = null;

         try {
             writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
             writer.append(fileContent);
             writer.flush();

         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
              try {
                  writer.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          return writer;
     }
 }
```

here is the LogCat

```
01-20 22:07:26.998: E/Trace(8471): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-20 22:07:27.929: D/gralloc_goldfish(8471): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-20 22:07:46.538: D/vvvvvv(8471): /data/data/com.example.emailandroid/cache/Report1916903470.csv
01-20 22:07:46.998: D/dalvikvm(8471): GC_CONCURRENT freed 201K, 5% free 4318K/4544K, paused 78ms+82ms, total 292ms
01-20 22:07:47.458: I/Choreographer(8471): Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 22:07:51.828: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8471): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-20 22:07:52.718: I/Choreographer(8471): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 22:09:40.928: I/Choreographer(8471): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

please show me where did i go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible because your gmail app doesnt have the permission to read from your data folder which is private. try to store the files in external storage.